# How to get the parent template component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I know in vue, I can use `this.$parent` to get the upper component in the vdom tree. But I'm expecting something different: to get the component that rendered the current component.

For instance, I have a component (named `comp-container`) with template:

```
<template>
  <comp-a>
    <comp-b></comp-b>
  </comp-a>
</template>
```

And in `comp-b` the `$parent` would be an instance of  `comp-a` not `comp-container` which I'm expecting.

My current aproach is traversing up with the `$parent` attribute until I find `comp-b` exists in `$options.components`. This method is working for now but seems quite ugly and breaks if `comp-b` is a globaly registered component. Is there an official way to do this?

Passing the parent template component via props as `<comp-b :container="this"></comp-b>` may do the job, but it's too verbose to be liked.

Comment: What is the reason you need to access the parent component ? Currently i does not make much sense.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do completely, but you can examine `$parent.$vnode.tag` and check to see if it contains the name of your container.

Comment: @TwilightSun - did you ever figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the exact use case, but basically if there are slots involved (which I almost assume, because otherwise $parent will work fine), you can find the rendering component at:
this.$slots.default[0].context;

Basically, the context property of a slot is the rendering context (rendering component - i.e. the component who's template the component was rendered in).

Only tested with Vue 2